# How can I change windows security settings using python? i.e. Password Requirements / Require Ctrl - Alt - Delete to log in

Tags: windows, vulnerability, python, windows-10, vulnerability-management

I am writing code in Python 2 or 3 to script Cybersecurity functions. Functions such as Lockout Duration, Password Length, and other things that involve a lot of clicking that could easily be automated.

```
import subprocess
subproccess.call(x, shell = True)
```

I plan on using that format to run (or enter ((so I don't have to type only press the answer button))) commands in command prompt (with Administrator privileges). However, I have no idea how I should do this, especially the "Require Ctrl - Alt - Delete on Startup." Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT :
As of now, I thought of a possible solution to the password requirement part of my problem that I will investigate, but am still totally lost on the ctrl - alt - delete part. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can set the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DisableCAD` to have value `0`.  The following command *should* (untested) do the trick:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DisableCAD /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will check this out!! I will also tell you if it works :D.  (because I can't just say thank you.) :) . Thanks a ton :D.

Answer (score 0):

As an overall way to do it, if you can find out which settings are contained in the registry, it's not difficult to create/write registry keys to which you have access.  Other settings, such as GPOs, are harder to do.  Sometimes you can change those with Powershell - so you may need to have Python call Powershell to configure some of those settings.  If you aren't on a domain and are using local policies, you can configure a master policy file that you have Python replace.

On the whole, if you're looking to configure settings for new devices, a better way to do that would be to create them on a VM and use DISM to snapshot a sysprepped image and then lay it down on a new device.  That's the more "Windows-y" way to do it.

Comment: How would I make that master policy python file? (as that would be amazing for my purposes!)